# Error al Poblar listview con cursor y sqlite

Tags: android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite

quiero poblar un listview con información desde una tabla de sqllite, pero me da error.

Esta es la estructura del proyecto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EN clientes fragment tengo el llamado al cursor de la siguiente manera

```
 private class ClienteLoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor> {

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... voids) {
       // showMessage("Leyendo Clientes");
        return mClienteDbHelper.getAllClientes();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cursor) {
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
           showMessage("Hay datos en la base :  "+ cursor.getCount());
           // mClienteAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
        } else {
            // Mostrar empty state
            showMessage("No hoy datos en la base "+ cursor.getCount());
        }
    }
}
```

El ClienteCursorAdapter solo tiene para llenar cada item del list

En la clase cliente declare un constructor con el cursor de la siguiente manera

```
public cliente(Cursor cursor){
    cMAId=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(clienterEntry.C_id));
    cMACODIGO = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(clienterEntry.C_codigo));
    cMANOMBRE = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(clienterEntry.C_nombre));
    cMADIRECCION= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(clienterEntry.C_direccion));
    cMACIUDAD= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(clienterEntry.C_ciudad));
    cMACANAL= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(clienterEntry.C_canal));
    cMALONGITUD=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(clienterEntry.C_longitud));
    cMALATITUD = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(clienterEntry.C_latitud));
}
```

En la dbHelper leo la tabla de la siguiente manera

```
 public Cursor getAllClientes() {
    return getReadableDatabase()
            .query(
                    clienterEntry.TABLE_CLIENTE,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);
}
```

AL ejecutar la app se me cierra y el logcat sale esto

```
04-21 12:28:48.722 18484-18484/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.cspm.ventas4.cspm, PID: 18484
                                               java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
                                                   at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:333)
                                                   at android.widget.CursorAdapter.swapCursor(CursorAdapter.java:378)
                                                   at com.cspm.ventas4.cspm.ClientesFragmet$ClienteLoadTask.onPostExecute(ClientesFragmet.java:106)
                                                   at com.cspm.ventas4.cspm.ClientesFragmet$ClienteLoadTask.onPostExecute(ClientesFragmet.java:94)
                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:688)
                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:705)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6524)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
```

Por donde estoy haciendo mal!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si alguien le sirve, la solucion fue que la crear la tabla el id debia ser _id para que el listview con el adapter puedan leer los datos.

```
public static final String TABLE_CLIENTE = "clientes";
    public static final String Cid = "_id";
    public static final String Ccodigo = "codigo";
    public static final String Cnombre = "nombre";
    public static final String Cdireccion = "direccion";
    public static final String Cciudad = "ciudad";
    public static final String Ctipo= "tipo";
    public static final String Ccanal= "canal";
    public static final String Clongitud= "longitud";
    public static final String Clatitud= "latitud";
```

Eso era todo.

Answer (score 0):

La columna _id no existe, revisa el query con el cual creaste tu tabla, si realizaste una prueba tal vez tengas que eliminar la aplicación y la vuelves a subir para que cree la correcta estructura.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

Comment: He verificado todo, el ingreso si funciona bien pero  la lectura da ese error. cambie de nombres todas las columnas y tampoco.